# Sort lines omitting a prefix of a certain length?

Tags: sorting, column

Many of my python files have an import section that looks like this:

```
from   datetime import datetime, timedelta
from   typing import Callable
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

I'd like to sort those lines by the library names. I'd like to run `sort-lines` but somehow tell it to overlook the first seven characters when assigning the order to a line, but to of course include those seven characters when it actually moves the line. That is, I'd like to end up with this:

```
from   datetime import datetime, timedelta
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from   typing import Callable
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it with `sort-lines` but you should be able to go one level below it and use `sort-subr`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C-h f sort-columns`:

> **`sort-columns`** is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
> `sort.el`.
>
> It is bound to `menu-bar edit sort sort-columns`.
>
> `(sort-columns REVERSE &optional BEG END)`
>
> Sort lines in region alphabetically by a certain range of columns.
>
> For the purpose of this command, the region `BEG`...`END` includes
> the entire line that point is in and the entire line the mark is in.
> The column positions of point and mark bound the range of columns to sort on.
> A prefix argument means sort into `REVERSE` order.
> The variable `sort-fold-case` determines whether alphabetic case affects
> the sort order.
>
> Note that `sort-columns` rejects text that contains tabs,
> because tabs could be split across the specified columns
> and it doesn't know how to handle that.  Also, when possible,
> it uses the `sort` utility program, which doesn't understand tabs.
> Use M-x untabify to convert tabs to spaces before sorting.

See also the Elisp manual, node [Sorting](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sorting.html):

> Command: `sort-columns reverse &optional beg end`
>
> This command sorts the lines in the region between `beg` and `end`, comparing them alphabetically by a certain range of columns. The column positions of `beg` and `end` bound the range of columns to sort on.
>
> If `reverse` is non-`nil`, the sort is in reverse order.
>
> One unusual thing about this command is that the entire line containing position beg, and the entire line containing position end, are included in the region sorted.
>
> Note that `sort-columns` rejects text that contains tabs, because tabs could be split across the specified columns. Use `M-x untabify` to convert tabs to spaces before sorting.
>
> When possible, this command actually works by calling the `sort` utility program.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on linux or Unix, you should have a sort command at the command line. Emacs has `shell-command-on-region` (on my machine, bound to `M-|`). Mark the region to sort, press `M-|`, and type `sort -k 2`. The sorted results appear in a buffer named `*Shell Command Output*`.

The -k option to sort tells what key (or field) to sort by.